# Check whether string has both white spaces or special characters

Tags: php, regex

Right now I'm checking whether a string is empty or has white spaces. So far this is my code and it works.

```
     if(isset($_POST['newTagSubmit'])){
    $tagName = $_POST['tagName'];
    if(empty($tagName)){
        $_ErrorMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='errorBox'>";
        $_ErrorMessage.= "<b>Error!</b> Por favor ingrese una etiqueta en el campo de texto proporcionado.";
        $_ErrorMessage.= "</div>";
    } else {
        if(preg_match('/\s/',$tagName)){
            $_ErrorMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='errorBox'>";
            $_ErrorMessage.= "<b>Error!</b> La etiqueta no puede contener espacios. Asegúrese de escribirla correctamente.";
            $_ErrorMessage.= "</div>";
        } elseif(/*code here*/){
            $_ErrorMessage = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='errorBox'>";
            $_ErrorMessage.= "<b>Error!</b> La etiqueta no puede contener carácteres especiales. Cáracteres especiales son todos aquellos que no estan dentro del alfabeto. Por favor escríbala de nuevo.";
            $_ErrorMessage.= "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

The first two if's work, the one where I check if string is empty and the other one is where i check if the string has white spaces.

Now I would like to check if the string has any special characters, but I have no idea how I could form a regex for that scenario. Can anybody help me please.

A little background from this project is, this is where I will be inserting tags for a help desk, the tags can be such words as:

-internet
-connection
-wireless
-router
-internet-explorer
-google-chrome
-firefox

etc.

EDIT:

By special character I mean everything that is outside the alphabet. Only allow A-Z, a-z.

Comment: This is possibly a silly question, but... What do you mean by a special character?

Comment: You could use something like: `if (preg_match('/[:punct:]/', $tagName)) {`. Not an accurate answer since you haven't specified what **you** mean by a *special character*.

Comment: by how that list of words look, it looks like you need `/[^a-z\-]/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this condition:

```
preg_match('/[^A-Z]/i',$tagName);
```

Removed `\s` since `[^A-Z]` also includes spaces.

Comment: what does the /i fragment stands for?

Comment: `/i` is for ignore case match.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to allow `A-Z` and `a-z`, using [ctype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) might be a better choice here:

```
if(!ctype_alpha($tagName)){
  // fail...
}
```